Complete reducibility and invariant subspaces of the defining representation of the Heisenberg group?
I just want to check my understanding on an exercise from Hall 4.5. Let the Heisenberg group be the matrix Lie group $H=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \Huge\vert \normalsize a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$. Does the defining representation (acting on $\mathbb{C}^3$) have any invariant subspaces?
From initial calculations, because it is a triangular matrix, the non-trivial invariant subspaces are $W_1=\mathrm{span}(e_1)$ and also $W_2=\mathrm{span}(e_1,e_2)$. How do I show that there are no other invariant subspaces?
And if there are no other invariant subspaces, then the defining representation is reducible but not completely reducible. Is this correct?

See Exercises, section $4.9$.

It's not reducible; none of the invariant subspaces have complements. So it's indecomposable but not completely reducible.

@QiaochuYuan Oh, so reducible is not the same as not irreducible?

@Landuros: hmm, Wikipedia disagrees with me so I don't know. I was under the impression that "reducible" meant "has a nontrivial direct summand" but according to Wikipedia it means "has a nontrivial invariant subspace" (so it's the same as not irreducible).
